# unnamed enum & typedef?

Tags: objective-c

I was getting a little confused with typedef/enum until I realised that I did not need to name the emun. Are there any differences / benefits between these two when used with typedef, the 2nd one to me seems a lot easier to understand.

First Example:

```
typedef enum enumMenuItems {
    none,
    add,
    save,
    load,
    list,
    remove
} menuItems;

menuItems optionSelect = none;
```

Second Example:

```
typedef enum {
    Earth = 1, 
    Mars,
    Saturn,
    Neptune,
    Jupiter
} planets;

planets closest = Mars;
```

.

## EDIT:

```
typedef enum enumMenuItems {
    none,
    add,
    save,
    load,
    list,
    remove
} menuItems;
```

So the above essentially defines two types, one an enum called enumMenuItems and the second a typedef of enumMenuItems called menuItems.

```
menuItems optionSelect = save;
enum enumMenuItems optionSelect = save;
```

The above two declarations are essentially the same, one using the typedef and the other using the enum. So if your using a typedef you can leave your enum unnamed as the type can be accessed via the typedef menuItem.

gary

Comment: I am a little confused by your edit, is the layout not just a matter of style / personal preference?

Comment: Sure, just wanted to differentiate better between the declaration and use of the enumerations.  NBD.

Comment: The comments in your edit seem basically correct.  There are some semantic quibbles, but in practice I don't think it matters.

Comment: Thanks Carl, I understand, go on then :) hit me with the semantic quibbles, I am certainly interested in getting things right.

Comment: Check out the FAQ link in my answer; it has all the gritty details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first case allows you to refer to the type as `enum enumMenuItems`.  For example:

```
enum enumMenuTimes optionSelect = none;
```

It might be clearer if you break it down into two parts:

```
enum _planets { 
    Earth = 1, 
    Mars, 
    Saturn,
    Neptune,
    Jupiter
};
typedef enum _planets planets;

enum _planets planet1 = Earth;
planets       planet2 = Mars;
```

If that simplifies the concept for you.  Your second notation there is just shorthand; it creates an anonymous enumeration and then uses `typedef` to give it a name.  You could even, for example, do:

```
enum {
    Value0,
    Value1,
    Value2
};
```

But you'd not be able to use the enumeration as a fake type name, like you're trying to do.  You can still access the enumerated values, though.

A more in depth description is available at the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/struct/typedef.html).